swagger editor - displaying multiple files at one through the URL
Following the doc here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor?tab=readme-ov-file#docker
I see that there is a way to run swagger editor with your own files
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -v $(pwd):/tmp -e SWAGGER_FILE=/tmp/swagger.json swaggerapi/swagger-editor
and then when you navigate to localhost you will see swagger.json displayed
Is there a way to have this happen dynamically instead of on each docker run build. For example
localhost/swagger vs localhost/swagger2 will display 2 different swagger files without me needing to do 2 docker run commands for that.

I found you can do this in swagger ui and swagger editor but not with swagger next. You need to pass in an env variable to the docker run.
swagger-ui:
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-ui
docker run -p 80:8080 -e QUERY_CONFIG_ENABLED=true swaggerapi/swagger-ui

http://localhost/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/examples/v2.0/yaml/api-with-examples.yaml - works
swagger-editor:
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-editor
docker run -p 80:8080 -e QUERY_CONFIG_ENABLED=true swaggerapi/swagger-editor

http://localhost/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/examples/v2.0/yaml/api-with-examples.yaml- works
swagger-editor next
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-editor:next-v5
docker run -d -p 8080:80 swaggerapi/swagger-editor:next-v5 

http://localhost:8080/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/examples/v2.0/yaml/api-with-examples.yaml - doesn't work
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-editor:next-v5
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -e QUERY_CONFIG_ENABLED=true swaggerapi/swagger-editor:next-v5 

http://localhost:8080/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/examples/v2.0/yaml/api-with-examples.yaml - doesn't work
